# Python 3 file handling txt or csv

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a file txt/csv file with delimiter as "~" Each value is separated by delimiter but also the value between the delimiter has "\n" character. I want an output file with each value is placed in each cell which includes newline character as well. How can I do this?

My File will look like below:

```
1~2~3~4~5~6~7~8~9~10~11~12~13~14~15~16~17~18~19~20~21~22~23~24~25~26~27~28~29~30~31~32~33~34~35~36~37~38~39~40~
284913111067~284913111068~284913111069~284913111070~284913111071~284913111072~284913111073~284913111074~284913111075~284913111076~284913111077~284913111078~284913111079~284913111080~284913111081~284913111082~284913111083~284913111084~284913111085~284913111086~284913111087~284913111088~284913111089~284913111090~284913111091~284913111092~284913111093~284913111094~284913111095~284913111096~284913111097~284913111098~284913111099~284913111100~284913111101~284913111102~284913111103~284913111104~284913111105~284913111106~
MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~MSS~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~SA~
U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~U~NE~NE~NE~NE~NE~NE~NE~NE~U~NE~U~NE~U~U~U~
0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~0~
284913380481;284913380482;284913380483;284913380484~284913380485;284913380486;284913380487;284913380488~284913380489;284913380490;284913380491;284913380492~284913380493;284913380494;284913380495;284913380496~284913380497;284913380498;284913380499;284913380500~284913380501;284913380502;284913380503;284913380504~284913380505;284913380506;284913380507;284913380508~284913380509;284913380510;284913380511;284913380512~284913380513;284913380514;284913380515;284913380516~284913380517;284913380518;284913380519;284913380520~284913380521;284913380522;284913380523;284913380524~284913380525;284913380526;284913380527;284913380528~284913380529;284913380530;284913380531;284913380532~284913380533;284913380534;284913380535;284913380536~284913380537;284913380538;284913380539;284913380540~284913380541;284913380542;284913380543;284913380544~284913380545;284913380546;284913380547;284913380548~284913380549;284913380550;284913380551;284913380552~284913380553;284913380554;284913380555;284913380556~284913380557;284913380558;284913380559;284913380560~284913380561;284913380562;284913380563;284913380564~284913380565;284913380566;284913380567;284913380568~284913380569;284913380570;284913380571;284913380572~284913380573;284913380574;284913380575;284913380576~284913380577;284913380578;284913380579;284913380580~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~Not Applicable~
--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~xbchbshfbjdzbuygeyrgjdzhzuihewu45hriuy78646213wsdcvbgdreser
bhbhgv

hbhdbfhzdxf   )_+)()*^

fddgfbduhygfdhxzxcvbnm


lkjhg
 gggffd bgdd fds aqwe rtyi opp,./'; []=-0987654321       



<>?":{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!


nhgdytsgfcusifu7fygtsygfyfrdfjhsd5e56
skjbftys
sfkndytfdtwsy6
trd
dgrdy
126;7';''',./';l[]]-=0

jhou8rdsj4nrzbwe4red
sb resyf
ASCVmnhgfstafdtg,./';[]=-0987654321<>?":{AASDFDFqeffrewrttg!@#$%^~--~--~--~
```

As you see from the above file, values between the delimiter has newline 
My output should be in csv with each value in single cell like:

```
1.....40
mss ...SA
```

Comment: Please provide a *[mcve]*. For example paste a sample of your file *and* include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Use the [edit] button to include a copy of your file into your question. Then show what the extracted data should look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can just supply `sep='~'` to the `.read_csv()` method from pandas (it will interpret `\n` as part of the appropriate field). So supposing your data file looks like this (`'blahs.csv'`):

```
# contents of 'blahs.csv':
h0~h1~h2
blah00~blah01~blah02\n
blah10~blah11~blah12\n
blah20~blah21~blah22\n
```

Then you can just import pandas and read it in like this:

```
import pandas as pd
blah = pd.read_csv('blahs.csv', sep='~')

blah
##     h0      h1        h2
## blah00  blah01  blah02\n
## blah10  blah11  blah12\n
## blah20  blah21  blah22\n
```

(And btw, pandas will interpret the newline character just like any other character, unless you tell it otherwise. See [official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for more info.)

Comment: my file will look like this which has newline between the text:--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~xbchbshfbjdzbuygeyrgjdzhzuihewu45hriuy78646213wsdcvbgdreser
bhbhgv

hbhdbfhzdxf   )_+)()*^

fddgfbduhygfdhxzxcvbnm


lkjhg
 gggffd bgdd fds aqwe rtyi opp,./'; []=-0987654321       



<>?":{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!


nhgdytsgfcusifu7fygtsygfyfrdfjhsd5e56
skjbftys
sfkndytfdtwsy6
trd
dgrdy
126;7';''',./';l[]]-=0

jhou8rdsj4nrzbwe4red
sb resyf
ASCVmnhgfstafdtg,./';[]=-0987654321<>?":{AASDFDFqeffrewrttg!@#$%^~--~--~--~

Comment: in between the "blah01" im having newline character like b\nla \n h01\n but all together blah01 should come in single cell of csv

Comment: yep, shouldn't matter -- `pd.read_csv()` will still parse it as one cell (at least in python 36 with a recent version of pandas). works as described no matter where `\n` appears.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is like this:

```
~hello
~this is an example
~i'm imagining what your file might be like
~i hope i'm right
```

Then this code should work:

```
file=open("info.txt", "r")
values=file.read().split("~")
values.pop(0)
```

Comment: this is for a txt file, i don't know much about csv, but i think you can use similar methods

Comment: My file will look like below which has newline character in it:--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~--~xbchbshfbjdzbuygeyrgjdzhzuihewu45hriuy78646213wsdcvbgdreser
bhbhgv

hbhdbfhzdxf   )_+)()*^

fddgfbduhygfdhxzxcvbnm


lkjhg
 gggffd bgdd fds aqwe rtyi opp,./'; []=-0987654321       



<>?":{}|+_)(*&^%$#@!


nhgdytsgfcusifu7fygtsygfyfrdfjhsd5e56
skjbftys
sfkndytfdtwsy6
trd
dgrdy
126;7';''',./';l[]]-=0

jhou8rdsj4nrzbwe4red
sb resyf
ASCVmnhgfstafdtg,./';[]=-0987654321<>?":{AASDFDFqeffrewrttg!@#$%^~--~--~--~

Comment: If what you have is a txt file with any amount of new lines in, and items seperated by '~', and you want to have a list, including each item, with new lines represented as \n, not including the ~, the above code should work even if items are not all seperated by new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not a CSV file. Each field has one trailing delimiter. Assuming the first row is a header, this would mean you have `40` fields. To parse this you need to read characters until `40` delimiters are found and then split on the delimiter (then skip over the next newline). This could be done using a generator function to return a row at a time as follows:

```
import re
import csv

delimiter = '~'

def get_row():
    with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input:
        delimiter_count = 0
        skip_newline = False
        row_chars = []

        for c in f_input.read():
            if skip_newline:
                if c == '\n':
                    skip_newline = False
            elif c == delimiter:
                delimiter_count += 1

                if delimiter_count == 40:
                    yield ''.join(row_chars).split(delimiter)
                    row_chars = []
                    delimiter_count = 0
                    skip_newline = True
                else:
                    row_chars.append(c)
            else:
                row_chars.append(c)

        yield ''.join(row_chars).split(delimiter)

rows = [row for row in get_row()]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0]).fillna('')
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

The resulting `output.csv` contains the cells correctly comma delimited, with the cell containing newlines enclosed in quotes. As such it would load correctly into Excel for example.

This could also be achieved using a multiline regular expression.

```
import re

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input:
    rows = re.findall('(([^\~]*\~){40}(\n|\Z))', f_input.read())
    rows = [row[0].rstrip('~\n').split('~') for row in rows]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows[1:], columns=rows[0]).fillna('')
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

This though will currently fail on your file as the final row only contains `29` delimiters. If you add eleven `~` characters to the end, it would work.